# When is it appropriate to use "late" when referring to someone who has passed?

Tags: idioms

I could never figure this out. Is this structure only for those who have *recently* passed?

> **The late** Steve Jobs...

Or can I use it to refer to someone who died a long time ago?

> **The late** George Washington...

Comment: Are you asking what the threshold is between being called 'late' and not having to bother?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much.

Comment: Note for later readers: a very similar question was asked again [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141350/how-long-can-you-say-the-late-so-and-so/142521#142521), and for some reason attracted a lot more detailed answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is most appropriate for use with those who were recently living.

For an explanation:

> The sense of "deceased" (as in the late Mrs. Smith) is from late 15c., from an adverbial sense of "recently."

-From http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=late&allowed_in_frame=0

Comment: The [handbook](http://www.etsy.com/listing/68430902/beetlejuice-handbook-for-the-recently).