# the late so and so

Tags: phrases

How long can you go back to call a dead person "the late so and so?"
JFK is sometimes called the late John F. Kennedy but I don't think Abrahm Lincoln is called the late Abraham Lincoln.
Are there any rules there?

Answer (score 1):

Garner in *Modern American Usage* (p499) has an excellent entry on this :

> **late. A. the late.** This expression is elliptical for *lately (i.e., recently) deceased*. How long this can be used of a dead person depends
>   on how recently that person died, but anything more than five years
>   or so is going to strike most readers as odd (e.g., *the late John F.
>   Kennedy*). Of course, there's no absolute statute of limitations; the
>   question is whether a fair number of reasonable readers would know or
>   need to be reminded that the person has died. But the expression
>   offers more than just a reminder. It also offers a note of respect -
>   and perhaps even a touch of sorrow. So in the fall of 1997 people
>   said  *the late Princess Diana* not because anyone needed to be reminded
>   that she had died in August of that year - everyone knew it - but
>   because people mourned her death. By the same token, a widowed spouse
>   might continue to use *my late husband* or *my late wife*.

---

Edit: The above answer has now been added to the original (identical) question at: [How long can you say "the late so and so"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141350/how-long-can-you-say-the-late-so-and-so) .